# Why do I get multiple tables for a single measurement in influxdb

Tags: regex, select, influxdb

When I use this SELECT I get the following output.

```
SELECT integral("value",1h)  / 1000 FROM /(Klima|NAS)_Power/ WHERE time > now()-1w AND time <= now() GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)
```

```
name: Klima_Power
time                 integral
----                 --------
2019-07-11T00:00:00Z 0.0028576888333333326
2019-07-12T00:00:00Z 0.05559535705833335
2019-07-13T00:00:00Z 0.055475250270833325
2019-07-14T00:00:00Z 0.0551049064541667
2019-07-15T00:00:00Z 0.055454312898611136
2019-07-16T00:00:00Z 0.05580957162916666
2019-07-17T00:00:00Z 0.05551291632777774

name: NAS_Power
time                 integral
----                 --------
2019-07-11T00:00:00Z 0
2019-07-12T00:00:00Z 0
2019-07-13T00:00:00Z 0
2019-07-14T00:00:00Z 0
2019-07-15T00:00:00Z 0
2019-07-16T00:00:00Z 0.1073428686286408
2019-07-17T00:00:00Z 0.7449990083701262
2019-07-18T00:00:00Z 0.756581078140122

name: Klima_Power
time                 integral
----                 --------
2019-07-18T00:00:00Z 0.05271264777916669
```

I want to create a graph in Grafana that shows stacked bars for multiple Measurements.
It works, but some Measurements are listet multiple times at the same time interval.

[image]

I guess I some how need to "group" the output so the values of the same measurement are listet in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple blocks(tables)  are  getting because you are executing select statement with [group by clause](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-tags). If you prefer to get distinct records as output you can use [distinct](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#distinct) function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.
Where do I put the destinct() command?
I tried some thing, but I don't get any results at all.

`SELECT destinct(integral("value",1h)  / 1000) FROM ....` or 

`... 0 FROM destinct(/(Schreibtisch|Beamer|NAS|Klima|Ventilator|Waschmaschine|Klima|Medien)_Power/) WHERE ....`